# Why repeat not working?

Tags: prolog

```
genVertex(List,Row,Col,Result) :-
   Col1 is Col,
   repeat,
   (Col \= Row ->   
   calculateSum(List,List,Row,Col1,Y),write(Y),write('\n'),
   Result = [Y|Tail]
   ;Result = Tail
   ),
   Col1 is Col1 + 1,
   Col1 == 5.
```

I want to call calculateSum with increment of Col + 1 until Col1 is 5?

Or any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

`repeat/0` probably doesn't do what you think it does. `repeat/0` creates an infinity of choice points. Basically use of `repeat/0` is only side effect predicates. I'd advise you not to use it until you properly understand Prolog execution (and even then, it's kind of a useless idiom).

try to implement a proper recursion instead (see [a tutorial](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch3) if needed). Another good solution here would be to use higher order predicates, but I wouldn't do that before getting basic Prolog.